# Trying to find a way to interpolate a big chunk of data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to create a mechanism that receives a txt file about the static test of a model rocket engine, to add time and then generate a thrust curve. From this curve, I need to extract the best fitting polynomial, in order to start the calculations. However, I'm having some trouble finding an effective way to perform the interpolation, since I can't transfer any algorithm to my program:

```
# The initial goal is to increment each line with its respective time, as this will be necessary for creating the graph
input_file_path = 'data.txt'
output_file_path = 'output_file.txt'

with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

# Processing each line and adding its respective time
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    time_value = i
    lines[i] = f'{time_value} {line}'

# The new content will be placed in another txt, which will then be used by the program to do the calculations
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(lines)

# Reading the txt file and extracting the data with the pandas library
data = pd.read_csv('output_file.txt',sep=' ',header=None)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Plotting the thrust curve with matplotlib
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("Thrust Curve")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Thrust (Newtons)')
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue', linestyle='-')
plt.show()
```

The txt file is going to be:

```
0 198 
1 20
2 20
3 20
4 20
5 20
6 20
7 20
8 20
9 20
10 20
11 20
12 20
13 20
14 20
15 20
16 20
17 20
18 20
19 20
20 20
21 20
22 20
23 20
24 20
25 20
26 20
27 20
28 20
29 20
30 20
31 20
32 20
33 20
34 20
35 20
36 20
37 20
38 20
39 20
40 20
41 20
42 20
43 20
44 20
45 20
46 20
47 20
48 20
49 20
50 20
51 20
52 20
53 20
54 20
55 20
56 20
57 20
58 20
59 20
60 20
61 20
62 20
63 20
64 20
65 20
66 20
67 20
68 20
69 20
70 20
71 20
72 20
73 20
74 20
75 20
76 20
77 20
78 20
79 20
80 20
81 20
82 20
83 20
84 20
85 20
86 20
87 20
88 20
89 20
90 20
91 20
92 20
93 20
94 20
95 20
96 20
97 20
98 20
99 20
100 20
101 20
102 20
103 20
104 20
105 20
106 20
107 20
108 20
109 20
110 20
111 20
112 20
113 20
114 20
115 20
116 20
117 20
118 20
119 20
120 20
121 20
122 20
123 20
124 20
125 20
126 20
127 20
128 20
129 20
130 20
131 20
132 20
133 20
134 20
135 20
136 20
137 20
138 20
139 20
140 20
141 20
142 20
143 20
144 20
145 20
146 20
147 20
148 20
149 20
150 20
151 20
152 20
153 20
154 20
155 20
156 20
157 20
158 20
159 20
160 20
161 20
162 20
163 20
164 20
165 20
166 20
167 20
168 20
169 20
170 20
171 20
172 20
173 20
174 20
175 20
176 20
177 20
178 20
179 20
180 20
181 20
182 20
183 20
184 20
185 20
186 20
187 20
188 20
189 20
190 24
191 30
192 44
193 58
194 76
195 97
196 118
197 122
198 131
199 123
200 124
201 112
202 107
203 105
204 99
205 99
206 109
207 112
208 124
209 120
210 127
211 122
212 120
213 123
214 129
215 130
216 130
217 131
218 136
219 138
220 141
221 144
222 143
223 146
224 150
225 152
226 153
227 153
228 157
229 163
230 165
231 164
232 164
233 166
234 167
235 170
236 173
237 173
238 173
239 174
240 177
241 181
242 184
243 183
244 182
245 184
246 185
247 188
248 190
249 190
250 190
251 191
252 189
253 192
254 192
255 193
256 194
257 196
258 196
259 197
260 196
261 197
262 197
263 198
264 193
265 196
266 195
267 196
268 195
269 197
270 198
271 200
272 199
273 199
274 199
275 199
276 199
277 200
278 200
279 197
280 199
281 198
282 198
283 198
284 199
285 197
286 197
287 197
288 197
289 196
290 195
291 194
292 194
293 192
294 192
295 191
296 190
297 189
298 189
299 187
300 187
301 186
302 186
303 183
304 184
305 185
306 183
307 181
308 179
309 178
310 177
311 178
312 174
313 171
314 170
315 169
316 170
317 170
318 165
319 161
320 160
321 160
322 162
323 157
324 153
325 152
326 151
327 150
328 149
329 143
330 142
331 141
332 143
333 142
334 138
335 132
336 132
337 131
338 138
339 129
340 123
341 121
342 124
343 133
344 121
345 116
346 111
347 113
348 109
349 108
350 102
351 100
352 98
353 95
354 93
355 89
356 88
357 85
358 82
359 81
360 79
361 76
362 71
363 70
364 69
365 64
366 63
367 60
368 56
369 56
370 54
371 50
372 47
373 44
374 42
375 40
376 36
377 33
378 31
379 20
380 20
381 20
382 20
383 20
384 20
385 20
386 20
387 20
388 20
389 20
390 20
391 20
392 20
393 20
394 20
395 20
396 20
397 20
398 20
399 20
400 20
401 20
402 20
403 20
404 20
405 20
406 20
407 20
408 20
409 20
410 20
411 20
412 20
413 20
414 20
415 20
416 20
417 20
418 20
419 20
420 20
421 20
422 20
423 20
424 20
425 20
426 20
427 20
428 20
429 20
430 20
431 20
432 20
433 20
434 20
435 20
436 20
437 20
438 20
439 20
440 20
441 20
442 20
443 20
444 20
445 20
446 20
447 20
448 20
449 20
450 20
451 20
452 20
453 20
454 20
455 20
456 20
457 20
458 20
459 20
460 20
461 20
462 20
463 20
464 20
465 20
466 20
467 20
468 20
469 20
470 20
471 20
472 20
473 20
474 20
475 20
476 20
477 20
478 20
479 20
480 20
481 20
482 20
483 20
484 20
485 20
486 20
487 20
488 20
489 20
490 20
491 20
492 20
493 20
494 20
495 20
496 20
```

I tried to apply the methods included in the scipy documentation, but I believe they are giving errors due to the amount of data to process. I thought about using numpy, but I don't have an idea of how to implement it.

Comment: How did you try scipy? Which errors did you get? Please include your best-effort code attempt. If your data doesn't many millions of entries, it's quite unlikely you bumped into a memory limitation. (If you really have that many data, you can start testing with a random subset.) Did you check the output of `data.info()` and `data.describe()`? Maybe some values are strings? You can force `read_csv`  to convert to floats (it will print an error if the data isn't convertable): `data = pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True, header=None, dtype=float)`

Comment: There is a part of this curve that is a constant 20, which implies that your thrust scale is measuring the weight of the rocket or something similar. You should remember to subtract that from the obtained thrust, or your calculations of total thrust will be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

So you know how to fit the data, but it's failing due to a memory issue? I am not clear on whether you have been able to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, so I've provided an example below using the data you included.

A simple approach is to try fitting the entire curve using a polynomial:

[image]

You could alternatively limit the fit to the thrust curve portion to get a better fit for that part. But it requires some processing to determine the hump's location and bounds:

[image]

Load data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = np.loadtxt('../new 2.txt').astype(np.float32) #the [time thrust] list of values

time_values = raw_data[:, 0]
thrust_values = raw_data[:, 1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("Thrust Curve")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Thrust (Newtons)')
plt.plot(time_values, thrust_values, color='tab:blue', linewidth=3, label='raw data')
```

Fit entire timeseries:

```
time_data = time_values
thrust_data = thrust_values

k = 5 #polynomial degree
def thrust_polynomial(x, *args):
    #model it using: C0 + C1*x + C2*x2 + ... + Ck-1 * x^k-1
    #e.g. it will become C0 + C1*x + C2*x2, if k=2
    return [np.polynomial.Polynomial(args)(xi) for xi in x]

params_mean, params_cov = curve_fit(thrust_polynomial, time_data, thrust_data, p0=[1] * k)

time_fine = np.linspace(time_data.min(), time_data.max(), num=500)
thrust_model = thrust_polynomial(time_fine, *params_mean)

#Add to plot
plt.plot(time_fine, thrust_model, linewidth=2, alpha=1, color='tab:red', label=f'fitted poly={k}')
```

Full code that allows you to switch between fitting the entire series or just the thrust curve part:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raw_data = np.loadtxt('../new 2.txt').astype(np.float32) #the [time thrust] list of values

time_values = raw_data[:, 0]
thrust_values = raw_data[:, 1]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_title("Thrust Curve")
ax1.set_xlabel('Time (seconds)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Thrust (Newtons)')
plt.plot(time_values, thrust_values, color='tab:blue', linewidth=3, label='raw data')

#
# Fit a curve
#
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

only_fit_hump = True

if only_fit_hump:
    #Find the general location of the hump:
    hump_time = (thrust_values/thrust_values.sum() * time_values).sum()
    hump_idx = np.argmin(abs(time_values - hump_time))

    #Find the points where data is flat
    grad = np.gradient(thrust_values, time_values)
    grad_smooth = pd.Series(grad).rolling(20).agg(lambda vs: np.abs(vs).mean()).values

    #Clip the hump between the flat parts
    pad = 1.20 #widen by 20%
    flat_part_end = hump_loc + np.argwhere(grad_smooth[hump_idx:] == 0)[0].item() * pad
    flat_part_start = hump_loc - np.argwhere(grad_smooth[hump_idx:0:-1] == 0)[0].item() * pad
    flat_part_start, flat_part_end = int(flat_part_start), int(flat_part_end)
    
    time_data = time_values[flat_part_start:flat_part_end]
    thrust_data = thrust_values[flat_part_start:flat_part_end]
else:
    time_data = time_values
    thrust_data = thrust_values

k = 5 #polynomial degree
def thrust_polynomial(x, *args):
    #model it using: C0 + C1*x + C2*x2 + ... + Ck-1 * x^k-1
    #e.g. it will become C0 + C1*x + C2*x2, if k=2
    return [np.polynomial.Polynomial(args)(xi) for xi in x]

params_mean, params_cov = curve_fit(thrust_polynomial, time_data, thrust_data, p0=[1] * k)

time_fine = np.linspace(time_data.min(), time_data.max(), num=500)
thrust_model = thrust_polynomial(time_fine, *params_mean)

#Add to plot
plt.plot(time_fine, thrust_model, linewidth=2, alpha=1, color='tab:red', label=f'fitted poly={k}')

if only_fit_hump:
    plt.axvline(x=hump_loc, linestyle='--', color='black', label='hump general location')
    lims = plt.axis()
    plt.fill_between(time_values[[flat_part_start, flat_part_end]],
                     y1=-100, y2=1e5,
                     alpha=0.08, color='black', label='fit domain')
    plt.axis(lims)
    
    plt.gca().twinx().plot(time_values, grad, label='gradient')
    plt.plot(time_values, grad_smooth, label='gradient smoothed')
    plt.ylim(-25, 25)
    plt.ylabel('gradient (clipped)')
plt.gcf().legend()
```